# move branches in team system

Tags: tfs, branch

I have the following scenario in my TFS:

```
MyTeamProject
      Trunc
          Sources
          Scripts
          Installations
      Prod
          Sources
          Scripts
          Installations
```

When prod is a branch of trunc.

Now I need to create versions under my production folder:

```
    MyTeamProject
      Trunc
          Sources
          Scripts
          Installations
      Prod
          V1.0.0
              Sources
              Scripts
              Installations
          V1.1.0
              Sources
              Scripts
              Installations
```

How can I move the current production to the version 1.0.0 folder, and still keep on the branch relation from trunc to v1.0.0 (previously "Prod")?
If i'll move one folder at a time (Sources, Scripts & Installations), I'll have the branch relation to the specific folders, and not on the entire Trunc.

Any Idea?

Comment: Not an answer, just a musing, I haven't moved branches in TFS yet. Could you simply rename Prod first, create a new Prod directory, and then branch from the renamed directory instead?

Comment: I can't make a new branch from the trunc, because it doesn't have the same version as prod. Actually, trunc contains the version I need to put in v1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been in this situation before, and it is actualy easy to solve once you have done it once:

1. Rename "$/MyTeamProject/Prod" to "$/MyTeamProject/v1.0.0" (You can't move the folder under itself)
2. Check-in
3. Rename "$/MyTeamProject/v1.0.0" to "$/MyTeamProject/Prod/v1.0.0"
4. Check-in

You can now crete a new branch from "$/MyTeamProject/Trunk" to "$/MyTeamProject/Prod/v1.1.0"